# z3: Bags as arrays

Tags: arrays, z3, first-order-logic

The below snippet is from the z3's tutorial : https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide

```
    (define-sort A () (Array Int Int Int))
    (define-fun bag-union ((x A) (y A)) A
      ((_ map (+ (Int Int) Int)) x y))
    (declare-const s1 A)
    (declare-const s2 A)
    (declare-const s3 A)
    (assert (= s3 (bag-union s1 s2)))
    (assert (= (select s1 0 0) 5))
    (assert (= (select s2 0 0) 3))
    (assert (= (select s2 1 2) 4))
    (check-sat)
    (get-model)
```

I'm unable to understand how does this line work -  `((_ map (+ (Int Int) Int)) x y))`

Also, I don't understand, why is the array s2 being assigned constant value of 4 from index [1,2] but not from index [0,0] in the below given output:

```
    sat
    (model 
      (define-fun s2 () (Array Int Int Int)
        (store ((as const (Array Int Int Int)) 4) 0 0 3))
      (define-fun s1 () (Array Int Int Int)
        ((as const (Array Int Int Int)) 5))
      (define-fun s3 () (Array Int Int Int)
        (store ((as const (Array Int Int Int)) 9) 0 0 8))
    )
```

I even tried adding more values to other indices of s2, but z3 only chooses value at [1,2] index as the constant value for the array. Can anyone explain what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In z3, `map` is a function that extends a point-wise operator to an array.

Let's say you have two symbolic int's. You can add them like this:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (= (+ x y) 4))
```

What happens if you have two arrays? SMTLib does not have a way of specifying "adding" two arrays, i.e., there's no way to say give me a new array that's the pointwise sum of two arrays. This is where z3's `map` extension comes in. You write it like this:

```
(declare-const arr1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const arr2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const arr3 (Array Int Int))
(assert (= arr3 ((_ map (+ (Int Int) Int)) arr1 arr2)))
```

Note again that this is a `z3` extension, and wouldn't work with other SMT solvers. What's happening above is that z3 will add `arr1` and `arr2` element-wise, and will require that to be equivalent to `arr3` due to the `arr3`.

(Aside: In the tutorial example, they're modeling bags; i.e., they have two integers stored in the map; so it's a bit more complicated. But otherwise the idea is the same.)

The *funny* ascription on `+` is required for type disambiguation. You can view it as saying: `(map + arr1 arr2)`. Unfortunately, SMTLib's type system is not strong enough to figure out which `+` you want as it is an overloaded operator. So, you have to explicitly give a type annotation by writing: `(_ map (+ (Int Int) Int))`. This is rather confusing syntax, but it is how you say I want "map" working on "+" at this instance. You can mostly ignore it.

I don't understand the second part of your question. The solver is free to pick any satisfying model whatsoever. Also, keep in mind the SMTLib arrays do *not* have bounds. i.e., any `Int` is a valid index. (This is in contrast to arrays in many programming languages.) Feel free to start another thread if you've further questions. (Stack-overflow works the best when each thread asks a single question.)